# Make Changes Take Effect in IIS

Tags: iis

If I make changes to anything under the Features View for a website in IIS, do I need to

1. recycle the  AppPool to get those changes to take effect
2. for any browsers already opened to that website should the tab be closed or a new tab be opened, or does the browser should be closed and reopened to see those changes?

I would like to the difference between iisreset, AppPool Start/stop, AppPool Recycle, and Website Restart options? Is there a good recommendation where I can read about this?

Comment: Unfortunately it is impossible to say Yes or No, because different settings require different ways to take effect. The only reliable way is to set up experiments and test out.

Comment: I'm interested in changes to Authentication. In particular Windows Authentication with respect to NTLM and Negotiate (Kerberos). If I remove, one of them, or promote one over the other, I'm interested in knowing what's involved getting the browser to recognize the change. Well, the minimal reset/recycle. For sure an iisreset and closing the browser would do the trick.

Comment: You can refer to: https://serverfault.com/questions/247425/what-is-the-difference-between-iisreset-recycle-refresh-and-restart

Answer (score 0):

**iisreset:** stop and start the World Wide Web Publishing Service.

**AppPool Start/stop:**

start: starting an application pool enables IIS worker processes to be created to serve requests in that pool.

stop: instruct all IIS worker processes serving this application pool to shut down, and prevent any additional worker processes from being started until the application pool is started again

**AppPool Recycle:** IIS will create a new process (keeping the old one) to serve requests.

**Website Restart:** stop and restart serving requests for that particular website.